# Sum of numbers using 2 functions

Tags: c

Just learning C and I'm trying to understand how I get the sum of numbers using 2 functions but the results is incorrect.

I'm trying to ask the user for 10 numbers which are stored in an array in function main. The sum is then calculated in a separate function and then displayed in main.

Here is my original code without multiple functions that works:

```
int main()
{
    int n[10];
    int index;
    int sum_n = 0;
    int largest_n;
    int smallest_n;
    int *p;
    p = &n[10];
    int a;

    printf("Enter 10 Integers\n");

    for (index = 0; index < 10;  index ++){
        scanf("%d", &n[index] );

        sum_n += n[index];

    }

    printf("The Sum of numbers is %d\n", sum_n);

}
```

Here is me trying to convert it to functions but the sum isn't working out:

```
int calculations (int);

int main()
{
    int n[10];
    int index;
    int largest_n;
    int smallest_n;
    int *p;
    p = &n[10];
    int a;

    printf("Enter 10 Integers\n");

   for (index = 0; index < 10;  index ++){
       scanf("%d", &n[index] );
   }
    if (n[index] = 10){
        //sum_n += n[index];
    printf("The Sum of numbers is %d\n",calculations(n[index]));
    }
```

&

```
    int calculations (int num){

        int sum_n = 0;

        sum_n += num;

        return sum_n;
}
```

When I run the second program using functions for numbers 1 to 10 I'm getting:

[image: cmd image]

I'm either doing something blatantly wrong or not understanding what I'm doing at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

every time you call a function the variables declared within a function are reset.
in case you want a variable that won't be reset every time you call a function you can simply make it static.

moreover you are passing and argument n[10] but your array stores number from n[0] to n[9] . And if you want sum of all ten numbers then you have to call calculation function for every number or you could just pass whole array. here is modified code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int calculations (int);

int main()
{
    int n[10];
    int index;
    int largest_n;
    int smallest_n;
    int *p;
    p = &n[10];
    int a;
    int ans=0;
    printf("Enter 10 Integers\n");

     for (index = 0; index < 10;  index ++){
        scanf("%d",&n[index]);
        ans = calculations(n[index]);
        }

    printf("The Sum of numbers is %d\n",ans);
}



int calculations (int num){

    static int sum_n;

    sum_n += num;

    return sum_n;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First you don't need `array` for `sum` in this code, Second always remember to *check* what returned by `scanf`.The code is very simple.

first part with `main`

```
  int main()
  {
   int n;
   int sum=0;

   printf("Enter 10 Integers\n");

   for (int index = 0; index < 10;  index ++){
       if(scanf("%d", &n))
           sum+=n;
  }
    printf("The Sum of numbers is %d\n",sum);//calculations(n));

}
```

Second using function `calculation`

```
  int sum=0;

  void calculation(int num){
        sum+= num;
  }

 int main()
 {
    int n;
    printf("Enter 10 Integers\n");

    for (int index = 0; index < 10;  index ++){
       if(scanf("%d", &n))
             calculation(n);
    }
    printf("The Sum of numbers is %d\n",sum);//calculations(n));

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `calculations()` simply returns its parameter (`0 + num` is simply `num`).

The statement

```
int sum_n = 0;
```

in it resets `sum_n` to `0` every time of calling it.

Move this statement out of it - directly into `main()` function (and before calling `calculations()`).

Answer (score 1):

Corrections mentioned in comments below.

```
int calculations (int *num){  //Should be a pointer or array eg. int num[] as you want to pass an array to this function

        int sum_n = 0;
        int i;

        //Create loop here to iterate over array and sum elements
        for(i=0; i<sizeof(num)/sizeof(int); i++)
        sum_n+=num[i];

        return sum_n;
}
```

And

```
 if (n[index] = 10){  //This is logically incorrect. This should be if(index==10). 
                     // n[index]=10 will assign 10 to a[10] and if will still pass as if(10) is true but make a note of it. Don't use assignment operator inside if, you need comparison operator `==`          

    printf("The Sum of numbers is %d\n",calculations(n[index])); //You should call calculations like this -> calculations(n). You should pass whole array not just an element.
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your help - the comments are understandable but i tried to use this method and kept getting "": 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode|

Comment: Okay to solve this, declare `i` outside for loop. `int i;` above function. That's my mistake. C++ allows initalization inside for loop but `C` doesn't. Let me update the answer.